# Spring Boot Batch use case for jobParameters and @JobScope/@StepScope over Environment/@ConfigurationProperties when configuring readers and writers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to write some code that is consistent and stylistically correct for Spring Batch Boot, and I'm looking for some feedback.

Spring batch classic step-scope example:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Partner> reader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters[pathToFile]}") String pathToFile){
    FlatFileItemReader<Partner> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Partner>();
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    itemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(pathToFile));
    return itemReader;
}
```

*pathToFile* is obtained as a job parameter passed from the command line. Step-scope is needed because of late binding.

In Spring Boot all arguments passed from the command line are automatically added to the Environment, and they are also available to beans created as @ConfigurationProperties.

Step-scope example refactored:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
protected class JobProperties {

    String pathToFile;

    ...getters/setters
}

@Autowired
private JobProperties jobProperties;

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Partner> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Partner> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Partner>();
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    String pathToFile = jobProperties.getPathToFile();
    itemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(pathToFile));
    return itemReader;
}
```

Assuming that *SpringApplication.setAddCommandLineProperties(false)* isn't going to be set, is there a case where @StepScope is preferable to the Environment/@ConfigurationProperties approach? Is one stylistically a better approach for Spring Boot? (Digging through the code the autoconfigurations surely rely a lot on @ConfigurationProperties).

Answer (score 2):

There are several differences between the two approaches.

One, you're essentially configuring the job by reaching into global state that Spring Batch doesn't know about. This defeats job parameter related functionality in Spring Batch. For instance, Spring Batch will refuse to execute the same job twice with the same parameters. You will also have more trouble restarting a job, as you'll have to make sure that the state that you set outside of Spring Batch is the same between the two runs.

Two, you lose the possibility of launching a job through other means than the command line (or at least you'll need to implement other methods to provide the same global state). This will cause problems if you want to run more than one job at the same time or if you want to test your jobs through functional tests.

Third, the scope of the `reader` bean is different on the two approaches. In your `@StepScope` example, the scope of the bean is set to `step`, in your refactored example the scope is `singleton`. In the latter case there will be only one object instance of the bean; in the former, there will be a new instance in every step that requests the bean (there will also be a singleton scoped proxy so that the bean can be injected into beans scoped differently).

Finally, with `@StepScope` you'll also be able to inject objects from the step `ExecutionContext` without going through e.g. the `ChunkContext`, which simplifies the code and testability.

BTW, in your first example, `reader` only needs to be `@JobScope`d for you to be able to inject the job parameters.

Comment: Those are good points. My primary use case is command line where Spring boot will execute a job using a local config file, so the bulk of the global state is managed there. I am providing a RunIdIncrementer, so at a minimum there is run.id=1,2,3... attached to the job. That said I would like to adopt some conventions where these could be run in a container/manager in the future, and what you've said makes sense.